# Que es lo que falla al intentar codificar variables categóricas para usar en mi algoritmo supervisado basado en RandomForest de scikitlearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Si tengo un archivo llamado `dataset.txt` con este contenido en el que se estructuran 4 columnas con variables categóricas (o sea no numéricas) sobre diferentes aspectos de estudiantes de la carrera de ingeniería, y lo que yo buscaba era entrenar un modelo **DecisionTreeClassifier** o su extensión que son los **RandomForest** con los datos de entrenamiento del txt, con el objetivo de posteriormente poder realizar predicciones con el modelo utilizando datos de prueba como muestro a continuación.

```
Sexo;Titulo_Preuniversitario;Situacion_Laboral;Años_Requeridos
masculino;tecnico;no trabajo;5 años
masculino;tecnico;trabajo;6 años
masculino;tecnico;no trabajo;5 años
masculino;bachiller;no trabajo;13 años
masculino;bachiller;trabajo;no termina
femenino;bachiller;no trabajo;8 años
femenino;bachiller;trabajo;no termina
femenino;bachiller;trabajo;no termina
masculino;bachiller;no trabajo;no termina
masculino;bachiller;no trabajo;8 años
femenino;tecnico;no trabajo;6 años
femenino;bachiller;no trabajo;10 años
femenino;mercantil;no trabajo;6 años
masculino;mercantil;trabajo;8 años
masculino;mercantil;trabajo;7 años
femenino;mercantil;no trabajo;6 años
femenino;mercantil;no trabajo;7 años
```

Siendo lo siguiente el **header** de las columnas que estructuran el dataframe:

`sexo;titulo_preuniversitario;estado_laboral;años_para_finalizar_estudios`

En donde la información esta organizada por sexos del estudiante(asumidos como `femenino` o `masculino`), titulo pre-universitario (`bachiller`, `tecnico` o `mercantil`), situación laboral durante su periodo de estudios universitarios(`trabajo` o `no trabajo`) y por último la cantidad de años que le llevo la carrera (o sea `n años` o en caso de no terminar se indica directamente como `no termino` en lugar del numero de años)

Usando python para estructurar la lógica del algoritmo me queda el siguiente código:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Leer el archivo dataset.txt y convertirlo en un dataframe
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.txt", sep=";")

# Separar las variables predictoras (X) de la variable objetivo (Y)
#X = data.drop(columns=["Años"])
X = data.drop(columns=["Sexo", "Titulo_Preuniversitario", "Situacion_Laboral"])
Y = data["Años_Requeridos"]

# Codificar las variables categóricas en valores numéricos
le = LabelEncoder()
X = X.apply(le.fit_transform)

# Dividir los datos en un conjunto de entrenamiento y otro de prueba
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

# Entrenar el modelo de Random Forest con los datos de entrenamiento
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
rf_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Realizar predicciones con el modelo utilizando los datos de prueba
rf_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)

# Entrenar el modelo de Árbol de Decisión con los datos de entrenamiento
dt_model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Realizar predicciones con el modelo utilizando los datos de prueba
dt_pred = dt_model.predict(X_test)
```

Una vez ya entrenado el modelo (asumo que correctamente), debería poder hacer estas predicciones a partir de nuevos datos que le vaya ingresando. Para ello, se hace la codificación de las variables categóricas de los nuevos datos (al igual que hice antes con el dataframe de entrenamiento), y he utilizado el modelo entrenado para realizar la predicción.

Por ejemplo, intente con este input `"femenino;;trabajo;8 años"` pero adaptado al formato de dataframe.

En este caso el dato que falta (y se busca predecir) es el del `Titulo_Preuniversitario`:

```py
# Codificar las variables categóricas de los nuevos datos
new_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Sexo": ["femenino"],
    "Titulo_Preuniversitario": [""],
    "Situacion_Laboral": ["trabajo"],
    "Años_Requeridos": ["8 años"]
})
new_data = new_data.apply(le.transform)

# Realizar la predicción con el modelo de Random Forest
rf_pred = rf_model.predict(new_data)
print("Random Forest:", le.inverse_transform(rf_pred))

# Realizar la predicción con el modelo de Árbol de Decisión
dt_pred = dt_model.predict(new_data)
print("Árbol de Decisión:", le.inverse_transform(dt_pred))
```

Pero **el problema es que me da este ValueError** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    encoded = np.array([table[v] for v in values])
KeyError: 'femenino'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    raise ValueError("y contains previously unseen labels: %s"
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'femenino'
```

Un resultado esperado (si esto funcionase correctamente) al intentar predecir la variable categórica faltante que tomaría el rol de **variable categórica objetivo (Y)**, y el resto de **variables de predicción o predictoras (X)**, seria algo como:

```
Random Forest: ['no termino']
Árbol de Decisión: ['no termino']
```

Que es lo que esta fallando? Hay algo que se este intentando codificar incorrectamente en lo que respecta a las variables categóricas dentro del conjunto de datos de entrenamiento del modelo?